# JavaScript Regex match with no match

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a RegEx `^(?:(?:3[0-9][0-9]{6,9})|(?:0[1-9][0-9]{6,9}))$` which works fine. But I want to add an excision of a specific number: `(?!(?:315678901))$` This works fine on its own. But combining the two messes the expression up.
Any ideas?

I was using it to include certain (Italian), phone numbers, but exclude one specific phone number.

Comment: How did you combine them?

Comment: ^(?!(?:315678901))$|^(?:3[0-9][0-9]{{6,9})$|^(?:0[1-9][0-9]{6,9})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use: `^(?!315678901$)(?:3\d|0[1-9])\d{6,9}$`

Here `(?!315678901$)` filters out **exactly** `315678901` and allows for other numbers matched by your expression. It also allows for numbers beginning with 315678901, but not 315678901.

Also, I compacted your alteration group to `(?:3\d|0[1-9])\d{6,9}`

Demo at [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WRQ1jC/3).

Comment: This works great except the any char (\d) causes other issues where I apply it. This is why I used an number ([0-9]. Once I swapped them out, ^(?!315678901$)(?:3[0-9]|0[1-9])[0-9]{6,9}$ it works!

Comment: @RobKing, what kind of issue do you have with `\d`?

Comment: The application I'm using needs to be number specific. \d includes any character.

Comment: @RobKing `\d` means any digit (the same as `[0-9]`).

Comment: @InSync I thought the same, but there is a difference. And I pulled my hair out, (and I don't have much hair), trying fix another RegEx until I replaced the \d with [0-9].

Comment: @RobKing In JS they means [exactly the same](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_expressions/Character_classes), unless you're using a third-party library.

Answer (score -1):

You can combine the two expressions using a positive lookahead assertion (?!...) to exclude the specific number 315678901 from the original expression. The resulting regular expression would be:

`^(?:(?!315678901)(?:3[0-9][0-9]{6,9})|(?:0[1-9][0-9]{6,9}))$`

Comment: Wouldn't that be a negative lookahead assertion?

Comment: Or even maybe a bit compacter version: `^(?!315678901$)(?:3[0-9]{7,10}|0[1-9][0-9]{6,9})$`

Comment: Also, your current regex filters out 3156789012, but I don't think it should.